# "Find usages" functionality as an IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to find a way in IntelliJ IDEA to find all the usages of a few library method calls and classes in a particular project.

The goal is to compile a list of classes which make reference to these specific methods or classes.

How can I go about this, I can see there is a `MethodReferencesSearch` which looks like it could be helpful, however the search method requires an instance of PsiMethod.

How can I create an instance of PSI method that matches the method in a particular lib class (say I wanted to find all the usages of the `concat(...)` method in Java's `String` class

Basically I'm trying to build a plugin that will generate a graph of certain method calls from within a project. For example something that would graph a set of routes by looking for certain method calls in a library. I.e. if Class A calls x(T) with type class B and class B calls x(T) with type of Class C, I would have a graph that looks like A -> B -> C etc. Find usages is great, it just doesnt work well for my needs.

Comment: Doesn't the "Find usages" (alt + F7) functionality already do what you describe?

Comment: If not, perhaps its "Analyze Backward Dependencies" feature is more to your liking?

Comment: I in the process of building a plugin that will generate a graph of certain method calls from within a project. For example something that would graph a set of routes by looking for certain method calls in a library. I.e. if Class A calls x(T) with type class B and class B calls x(T) with type of Class C, I would have a graph that looks like A -> B -> C etc. Find usages is great, it just doesnt work well for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the true PsiMethod by JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(...).findClass("java.lang.String", ...allScope(...)).findsMethodByName("concat", false)[0]. This method can then be passed to MethodReferenceSearch.

Comment: Thats great thanks! Is there a Scala equivalent? How does this work for overloaded methods?

Comment: findClass is language-agnostic, it'll find Scala classes as well. As for overloaded methods, you'll get several if you search by name and you can find the needed one manually. Or you can use findMethodsBySignature, but it's a bit more complicated. To make a pattern method, you might want to use JavaPsiFacade.getElementFactory.createMethodFromText

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming that you can't guarantee that you have a usage of `concat` easily available (for example, at the user's cursor position in an open document).

A hacky way to do it would be to create a small, correct, self-contained java class in a String, like below:

```
class Nothing { String s = "a".concat("b"); }
```

Then, there is a way (if I remember correctly) to use IntelliJ to parse the class contained in this String, thereby giving you a `PsiReference` to the method you want to find usages on (in this case, `concat`).

Would this approach be useful to you?

If so, I can dig out a code example on how this can be done.