# Get usages of .class references for a PsiClass

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

How to find all the references to `Foobar.class` when I have a `PsiClass` object to `Foobar`?
The point of my question is *not* what utility function should I use to find the PsiElement for class (Foobar) but for class object (Foobar.class). I don't see how this is exact duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425237/find-usages-functionality-as-an-intellij-plugin). Unless PsiClass also represent the class object. If it is so then I'd be glad if someone explains it to me, as PsiClass documentation says only "Represents a Java class or interface."

- Is it possible to get the class object (as PsiElement) based on `PsiClass`? If I look a code using Psi Viewer that has class object, it has `PsiClassObjectAccessExpression`but how do I construct that object?
  I need PsiElement so that I could use utility functions such as `com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ReferencesSearch.search`

Usecase: somewhere in the project there is a statement `myMethod(Foobar.class);`. I need to find myMethod and all the other places where the class object of Foobar is referenced.